# Calculating limit $\lim \frac{1}{x}\sin \frac{1}{x} $

Tags: real-analysis, limits, infinity

$$\lim \frac{1}{x}\sin \frac{1}{x} = \infty $$ when $x \to 0$

But by the graph I doubt we should get an infinite oscillating discontinuity and so the limit does not exist here. But I am unable to point out the flaw. Please help or suggest.

Comment: Hi, it is not a $\frac{0}{0}$ limit !

Comment: Oh yes! I got my fault.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let
$$f(x)=\frac 1x\sin(\frac 1x)$$

$$u_n=\frac{1}{n\pi}$$
$$v_n=\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi}$$

then

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}u_n=\lim_{n\to+\infty}v_n=0$$

$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(u_n)=0$$
$$\lim_{n\to+\infty}f(v_n)=+\infty$$

can you conclude.

Answer (score 0):

As a hint , you can take $\frac 1x=a$ so $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1}{x}\sin \frac{1}{x} =\\
\lim_{a \to \infty} \frac{1}{\frac1a}\sin \frac{1}{\frac1a} =\\
\lim_{a \to \infty} a\sin a =?$$

Comment: Note that even though $a\to\infty$ only covers the $x\to 0^{+}$ case, it is good enough since it demonstrates the nonexistence of one side of the limit.

Comment: Okay thanks. But I am still unsure about the graph, as it looks as if it's oscillating. Can I say here that the limit exists infinitely?

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha That doesn't mean anything.

Comment: the first equality sign is true but misleading because you only knows its valid when realized that the limit doesn't exists

Comment: Okay I got it now.

Comment: @ShatabdiSinha: Oscillation shows that ,the limit does not exists.

Comment: @Khorsotash Yes exactly, I understood it.